# Drawing a hooked up arrow in a commutative diagram

Tags: arrows, tikz-cd

Here is my code:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{document}

\[
\begin{tikzcd}
S^2 \cup_{m} D^3 \arrow[r, "i\circ \phi \circ q"] \arrow[d, "q"] &[0.5em] 
S^2 \cup_{n} D^3 \arrow[d, "i"] \\
S^3 \arrow[r, "\phi"'] & S^2 
\end{tikzcd}
\]
\end{document}
```

But I have had hard time trying to make the arrow labeled "i" hooked and pointing upward instead of downward, could anyone help me in adjusting this please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzcd}
S^2 \cup_{m} D^3 \arrow[r, "i\circ \phi \circ q"] \arrow[d, "q"] &[0.5em] S^2 \cup_{n} D^3  \\
S^3 \arrow[r, "\phi"']                                           & S^2 \arrow[hookrightarrow,u, "i"] 
\end{tikzcd}
\end{document}
```